# Basic Entropy Inequality and Identity question

Tags: information-theory, entropy

This is a solution to a problem I am working on:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
H(X|Y) + H(Y|Z) &\ge^? H(X|Y, Z) + H(Y|Z) \\
&=^\text{?}H(X,Y |Z) \\
&= H(X|Z) + H(Y|X, Z)\\
&\ge H(X|Z)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Can someone explain to me where the first inequality and identity come from. Why would adding a another random variable decrease entropy in the first inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first inequality means that in general conditioning may reduce the information. If you prefer, note that $$H(X)\ge H(X|Z)$$ and then condition on $Z$ on both sides. For the identity, similarly, since $$H(X|Y)+H(Y)=H(X,Y),$$ after conditioning on $Z$ on both sides you get the inequality above.

Comment: I'm sorry I am still a little confused. For the first inequality, we isolate $H(X|Y)$ and ignore $H(Y|Z)$, right?

Comment: Right. --------

Comment: But, then are you saying $H(X|Y) \ge H(X|Y, Z)$ generally? Because this seems a little counterintuitive, as you aren't conditioning with with regard to $Z$. You are just finding the joint entropy of the distribution of $X|Y$ and $Z$.

Comment: $H(X|Y,Z)$ means $H(X|(Y,Z))$, although you may perhaps use another notation. Indeed we are conditioning with respect to $Z$.

Comment: Ohhh... I was taking it as being equivalent to $H(Z, X|Y)$. I feel silly. Thanks!